# каким образом функция может обращатся к записи словаря? пример нужен!

Tags: python-3.5

[image: введите сюда опис787ание изображения]Мне нужно функцией подсчитать сумму записей, которые хранятся в словаре.
Тип данных записей - `int`. Пример словаря:

```
stock = {
    "banana":  6,
    "apple":   0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear":   15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple":  2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear":   3
}
```

[image: это из онлайн урока задание ,выбивает ошибку ,как бы по примеру ниже пытался сделать но не получается,не могу понять причину ошибки]

Comment: Только не понятно, что Вы хотите тут узнать. Приведённый код правильный, указанная ошибка к нему не имеет никакого отношения. Приводите именно тот код, который эту ошибку вызвал.

Comment: @Эдуард Измалков  спасибо Вам за ответ,всё видимо верно ,это онлайн обучалка просит чтоб я включил + PRO за деньги или иначе я не перейду на следущий уровень -обучения ,я возможно не правильно трактую само задание ,там условия немного непонятные,задача на английском а переводчики не доскональны в плане перевода) Я скопирую и покажу ,если есть возможность  гляньте пожалуйста !Вот Задача! 
зараз ниже скину!

Comment: 01. Define a function compute_bill that takes one argument food as input.
02. In the function, create a variable total with an initial value of zero.
03. For each item in the food list, add the price of that item to total.
04. Finally, return the total.

Ignore whether or not the item you're billing for is in stock.

Note that your function should work for any food list.

Comment: Определите функцию , compute_billкоторая принимает один аргумент в foodкачестве входных данных.
02. В функции, создать переменную totalс начальным значением, равным нулю.
03. Для каждого элемента в foodсписке, добавьте цену этого пункта к total.
04. И, наконец, .returntotal

Игнорировать ли элемент или нет, вы биллинг для на складе.

Обратите внимание , что ваша функция должна работать для любого списка продуктов питания.

Comment: Да нет, код на скриншоте соотвествует заданию и корректен. В ошибке ссылка на неправильную строку `compute_bill(['apple'])`. Эту ошибку не может вызывать привёденный код. Следовательно либо Вы приводите не всё, либо интерпретатор что-то выдумывает сам.

Comment: скриншот скину ,если получится

Comment: http://ideone.com/foOgdP вот результат работы Вашего кода

Comment: да я увидел ,спасибо ,э-э-э-э-х)

Answer (score 0):

Все значения словаря можно получить при помощи метода [`values`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values),
а получить сумму можно применив функцию `sum`

```
In [8]: stock.values()
Out[8]: dict_values([0, 6, 32, 15])

In [9]: sum(stock.values())
Out[9]: 53
```

Comment: понимаете @Александр Зинин ,условие задачи такая ,создать собственную  функцию ,в которой будет цикл for,в котором нужно обратится к некоторым спискам ,и например сума сумой ,а если условие другие задачи ,что если будет строковой тип и мне нужно редактировать  на своё усмотрение !? ну также из типом данных int ,например нужно применить условие внутри функции ,типа на сравнение чисел или будь какого действия , общем совсем не то ,что я ищу ,жаль,а так спасибо за совет!